# Invalid use of incomplete type for named template argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I have the following class template:

```
 template<typename T=class idType, typename U=class uType>
 class f {

    std::unordered_map<T::Type, float> id_; // error!

 }
```

I am using the dependency injection framework `boost::di` and I therefore need to name my template argument to be able to bind those templates to actual types.  I am surprised  that I get an error when I try to declare a hashmap using the underlying type of the template `idType`. Yes, I would imagine an error if the template argument I use did not have defined a `Type`, but I certainly do in my case. They are defined after I include the file containing the example above.

The error is:

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class idType’
   14 |     std::unordered_map<typename T::Type, float> rpc;
      |                                                          ^~~
example.hpp:9:29: note: forward declaration of ‘class idType’
    9 | template<typename T = class idType, typename U = class uType>
```

Comment: Do `idType` and `uType` exist at the point where you've written that template? That is, are they defined?

Comment: They are defined after I include the file containing the example above

Comment: ... why would you expect that to work? I mean, C++ is fairly strict in that you can't generally refer to things that don't exist yet.

Comment: @A2LBK The error message does not match the code. In the code it says `idType::Type`, but in the error message it says `typename T::Type`. The difference is potentially significant since it makes the type dependent. Also, please show a full [mre] for the problem. The exact order of declarations/definitions and uses of the template is relevant.

Comment: Well it is a template argument. It is like e.g. invoking a function that is part of a template argument. In fact, taking out the named ´class idType' it should then work ?

Comment: @A2LBK `typename T=class idType` vs `typename T=idType` is also a potentially significant difference since the former can declare a new type while the latter can't, but it is not the difference I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> They are defined after I include the file containing the example above

Yeah, that's not gonna work.

While templates and class definitions do have some specific leeway in that they can sometimes reference things declared/defined after them, these are very specific cases. The bodies of class member functions can reference other elements of their own class that have not at that point been declared (essentially, the compiler moves the member function definition to just after the class definition).

And templates can reference as-of-yet undefined names... so long as those names are *dependent* on a template parameter.

The code you've presented uses `idType`, which is not a template parameter name. The *parameter* is `T`; `idType` is merely the default value of that parameter. If the user provides a different type, your use of `idType` will ignore it.

Therefore, the compiler must search for `idType` at the point of use within the template, not at instantiation time.

Indeed, the fact that you use `idType` as a default value at all also imposes the requirement that type needs to exist at the location of the template definition. You named it, after all; it needs to exist if you name it.

Comment: But even if I change it to ´T::Type´ won't compile either

Comment: @A2LBK: I added a thing at the end which explains that issue.

Comment: Ahh okay. I understand the limitation. Anyway I could wrap around deducing the Type of class T ?